# How to retrieve rowId from javascript postBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I bound in my gridview, `OnRowCreated` event to each row following javascript code

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridViewCategory, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

And now my question is how can I retrieve this `rowIndex` in postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the [SelectedIndexChanging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging.aspx) event

Comment: true but then i have this error: Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.

Comment: And further suggested to register event for validation, right?

Comment: Yes, f the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation, is this save?

Comment: Yes it's save if you trust yourselves :)

Comment: ok i used render method and how it works, can u tell me how can I retrive now this index number in SelectedIndexChanging event?